# What is the point of choosing closest node in Dijkstra algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

In all articles which I read, neighbor to process first is "closest" neighbor. But finally it's needed to visit all nodes to figure out all possible paths. So, the question is - why do we do this? I believe the same result can be achieved if we simply traverse Graph in BFS way and will perform calculation of costs. For example:
[image]

first step- 0, costs table:
2 - 6 |
3 - 2 |

second step- 2, costs table:
2 - 6 |
3 - 2 |
1 - 9 |

third step- 3, costs table:
2 - 6 |
3 - 2 |
1 - 9 |
4 - 12 |

forth step- 1, costs table:
2 - 6 |
3 - 2 |
1 - 9 |
4 - 12 |
5 - 12 |

fifth step- 4, costs table:
2 - 6 |
3 - 2 |
1 - 9 |
4 - 12 |
5 - 12 |

With simple BFS traversing the cheapest way was find out. What do I missing?

Comment: "But finally it's needed to visit all nodes to figure out all possible paths" - this is not what Dijkstra's algorithm does. Dijkstra's algorithm will not bother to take other routes if it can already be determined that a particular vertex edge won't beat the current best route.

Comment: The graph you posted is not a good example because an exhaustive traversal **is** necessary to determine the best route. If you look at other graphs, especially undirected cyclic graphs (e.g. the US interstate highway map) then the algorithm's built-in optimizations become apparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the path from `A` to `B` and `B` to `C` are both cost 1, and the direct route from `A` to `C` is cost 3.  (In the real world, the first two are highways that bypass a mountain while the third is a tiny trail over a mountain pass.)

Dijkstra will route you `A -> B -> C` for a total cost of 2 while BFS will route you `A -> C` for a total cost of 3.

Therefore you have to process lowest cost first to get the right answer.

Comment: Still can traverse all nodes, and get correct answer. Actually I feel confused. One talks that when we implement Dijkstra it has to visit all nodes, and other - that it's not necessary. Probably it's a little bit different question, but to answer initial one, I need to understand which way is correct, explain it please.

Comment: @GordienkoR. There are variations on Dijkstra's algorithm.  The usual and original variant is the shortest path from a source to a target, and it will visit as few nodes as it can get away with.  Another is to build a tree of the best paths from a source to **every** other node.  That one has to visit all nodes.

Comment: If you are thinking of the second variant then my answer should change.  Least cost first will only have to visit nodes once.  Breadth first has to visit them over and over again every time it finds a cheaper path there.  Breadth first now will produce the right answer, but will be much slower.

Answer (score 2):

At each step, Dijkstra's algorithm extends the lowest-cost path known so far.  Thus, when you finally encounter the goal state, you know that all other, unfinished paths have a greater cost.  Therefore, the one you just found is the shortest path.